# Eclipse doesn't work after installing react native

Tags: eclipse, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, react-native, i386

To install react native I executed:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

After doing this Eclipse crashes.

Comment: How does Eclipse crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eclips is 64bits version, and doesn't support 32 bits architecture.